# ConstraintLayout, best practices, banded background

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I am creating a background (as in the figure), which has 3 colors divided equally (same width).

[image]

Today I am using the following code:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp">

        <View 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"/>
        <View 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"/>
        <View 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="@color/colorRed"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I'm using the combination of LinearLayout and three Views with their weight. **Since I started using ConstraintLayout I am trying to reduce the amount of Views of the XML, I believe I can reduce this in question**.

I've tried creating a 3px by 1px image as background, but when I use fitXY it turns a gradient.

Is there a solution that involves using a single View that I can create this background (same width and three different colors)?

Comment: And what's wrong with using gradients?

Comment: If you you want a single view then you better look at custom view and manual use of `canvas.drawPath`

Comment: @TamirAbutbul how to used as banded (fixed point) ?

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich that's a memory eater way

Comment: So you can look here https://android.jlelse.eu/constraint-layout-performance-870e5f238100 and https://medium.com/@krpiotrek/constraintlayout-performance-c1455c7984d7 or the same ones. You can try to find newer info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `guidelines` or `chains`, for this, I would like to use chains:

In the example below I have 3 buttons with a horizontal chain - they are all got the same width so now all left to do is to set the background color for them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@color/some"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks like this :

[image]

For more information, you can check [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html)

Comment: Why not use View instead of buttons? Was it just your choice?

Comment: ye it was my choice, use any view that you want , the buttons are there just to show you that it will work on all kind of views

Comment: this xml is dirty, bias attribute is totally useless in this case, referring to another id should be without +, like this "@id/anotherId"

Comment: @Eugene great, I have learned something new so first thing thank you. second - this is the default reference that android studio create when I am working with the design option for constraintLayout, any idea how to prevent it from adding the + ?

Comment: don't know :( but it works in both cases - with/without "+", I didn't want to be rude, my english is not good enough

Comment: rude? you were great, you have  told me something new that I didn't knew before - you rock

Comment: @Eugene check [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536227/constraintlayout-weird-attributes-behavior-when-constraining-2-views/55536292#55536292) it explain really good the +id thing

Answer (score 2):

***Check this easy solution to understand it will fillfull your requirement***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10_dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#212121"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#3cff42"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#f93d3d"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What? yes you can, with guidelines and 3 views

Comment: I am writing my answer as we speak

Comment: @Ashok Reddy M hey buddy check my answer - I think that you can learn a lot from it.

Comment: There is not nesting required in Constraint Layout, this is the specialty of Constraint Layout