# ConstraintLayout weird attributes behavior when constraining 2 views

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Let's say that I want to connect one view to another with `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` (it can be any other constraint).

If I will do it manually from the XML display it will be something like this:

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/something"
```

**But** - If I will do **the same thing** with the design option and not the XML option I will get extra `+` (auto generated) char for some reason and it will look like this :

```
  //notice the extra + in @+id
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/something"`
```

Now the funny thing is that the app will run with or without the + char.

So - looks like I don't really need that extra + char while referring to other views, my question is **why** this is happening and **how** can I prevent android studio layout editor to add this +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The +id is only needed the first time an id is mentioned in the xml.

It can still be useful to have the + every time in case you want to reorder the xml in the future.

I would not worry too much about this. Doing +id likely has an extremely low build-time performance hit. (See if you can measure the difference. I doubt you can.)